# Are the pronunciations for 'él' and 'el' different?

Tags: pronunciación

I wonder if él and el are pronounced differently.

I can hear the sound [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9l#Spanish) for él, but there is no sound file for el [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/el#Spanish)

Comment: Pronunciation and stress on a word are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonetically they are pronounced the same, but the pronoun is always stressed, while the article isn't. A good example to see the difference is "*él camina*" (he walks) vs "*el camino*" (the path). In the first one there is stress in the é and the i, while the second one is pronounced as a single word with the stress in the i.

Answer (score 3):

Es el mismo fonema pero distinto énfasis. Por ejemplo, la frase:

> Le dije a él si me podía prestar el libro de historia.

No suena monótona, la pronunciación sería algo como:

> Le-dije a-**ÉL** ; si-me-podía prestar el-libro de-historia

Es muy similar a las reglas del *stress* para las frases en inglés. A los pronombres, sustantivos, verbos, adverbios y demás palabras que aporten significado se les da mayor énfasis y por lo tanto hay que hacer una pequeña pausa al pronuncuarlos. A lo demás (preopsiciones, conjunciones, artículos, etc.) se le da menos énfasis y suenan como si estuvieran pegados a las palabras importantes. Casi siempre que veas un monosílabo con tilde, la misma te indica que tenés que darle más énfasis y por lo tanto al pronunciarlo tenés que detenerte un poquito más que en el caso en el que no lleva tilde—de hecho no se me ocurren excepciones a esta regla y fue así como aprendí a distinguir cuándo tildar los monosílabos en los casos que admiten varios significados.

Answer (score 2):

The pronunciation is exactly the same but not the meaning:

- Él = pronoun masculine singular
- El = article masculine singular

They are *homophones*: differently spelling, same pronounciation

Comment: Yes, the pronunciation is the same but the stress in the sentence is most likely not the same.